How to repair stone veneer corners broken off by screw anchors
I have a stone veneer wall we’re replacing shutters on. The existing holes drilled for the plastic screw anchors for the old shutters have caused some of the stone corners to break. We need to repair these as well as extract the old plastic anchors and patch the holes so we can redrill to install the new shutters. What would be the best material to repair and patch fake stone?
Damaged stone veneer 1
Damaged stone veneer 2

How about including a picture or two so we can see what you see.

Added link to photo.

Assume you've lost the pieces that broke off?

I will expect this to be a 2 or 3 step process. It will require using tile grout, since it comes in colors that could match the color of your stone.
You will need to mix up a small amount at a time to apply the grout in coats/layers. It can be mixed in a paper cup with an ice cream stick. Don't be shy, use your fingers to push it onto the surface of the damaged area so it is certain it makes good contact. A stick will only go over the high spots and not force it into the crevices like your fingers will. Make the last thing you do when applying the grout is to wipe around the perimeter of the damaged area with grout to seal the grout to the perimeter.
Have a very, very slightly damp sponge to wipe off the edges that will smear onto the areas of intact stone. The material will not like being built up a lot all at once, so do the same thing again, and again to get the prefered depth to finish the fix.
An additional note about the sponge. It has to be nearly dry when being used. It cannot be dry, and it must be damp. If it is too damp, the excess water in the sponge will immediately dilute the grout you are using, and the grout will start to bleed al over the place.
One final mention, mix the grout so it is thicker than peanut butter, almost dry enough to crumble, to dry it will not stick. No need to dampen the surface of the stone first, see note about the too damp sponge.
About reinstall the shutters. DO NOT reuse these areas to drill again. The reason they failed is the holes were drilled closer than 2" from an edge/end. Holes must be kept far enough away so cracking will not occur.

Thanks for the info, Jack!  Color isn’t that important since all will be behind shutters. The main thing I was worried about is using something that would crack with stone temp changes with cold and heat.
